# iOS application connect to .NET Webservice by GET method

Tags: ios, web-services, get

everyone! My english is poor and sorry fot that.

I want implement a function in my test iOS application.

There is a .NET Webservice API just like

**"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/Login"**

I want to connect the API with two parameters：user and pass

using the GET method,and the url will be like:

**"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/Login?user=xxx&pass=xxx"**

if login, the Webservice will return a JSON value just like {"d":"success"}

if not, it will also return a JSON value like {"d":"failure"}

I am using the ASIHTTPRequest framework and JSON framework

I dont know how to implement the function. So please help me, thanks a lot.

Best wishes!

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://192.168.1.245/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/Login?user=jiangxd&pass=123456"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];

[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];

[request setDelegate:self];

[request startAsynchronous];

NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];

NSString *unlockCode = [responseDict objectForKey:@"d"];

NSLog(@"%@",unlockCode);
```

The unlockCode is always null... and I dont understand why!

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://192.168.1.245/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/Login?user=jiangxd&pass=123456"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) 
{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSString *unlockCode = [responseDict objectForKey:@"d"];
    NSLog(@"%@",unlockCode);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}
```

And now I change startAsynchronous to startSynchronous but there is also an error:

**Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (Possible causes may include a bad/expired/self-signed certificate, clock set to wrong date)" UserInfo=0x6b81640 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6b811b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)", NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (Possible causes may include a bad/expired/self-signed certificate, clock set to wrong date)}**

**NOTICE:The url is https, not http!**(Is this the reason that I get an error?)

But if I access the url directly with browser， the Webservice will return the right value...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably try it, and then post your code.  You're asking someone to write this entire function for you, and I don't think that that is the purpose of this site.

Secondly, the developer behind the ASIHTTPRequest is no longer supporting it.  Unless the community picks up, you might want to just learn how to do NSURLConnections from scratch.

Edit:  There we go.  So, you're doing this asynchronosly which means that when you start it, you're not immediately going to have the response.  Have you setup your callbacks to process the response?

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

Comment: Okay.  Now, this is a completely different issue.  SSL/TLS connections are complex.  Whenever you do something with a browser with https, a lot of things are being done for you, that you have to do manually in code.  I suggest closing this question (accepting an answer) and start up a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will close this question and start up a new one!

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with the ssl stuff.